# Prove $[0, 1]$ and $(0, 1]$ are equinumerous

Tags: real-analysis

I am having a bit of trobule here. THis post was marked duplicate HOWEVER the open and closed segments were different.

My thought is this:

What my thought was that the bijection was a piecewise function:

$f(x) = 1/(n+1)$ if $x = 1/n$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$ and $x=1/n$ if $x \neq1/n$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$.

However, the textbook says this is incorrect. I don't actually see why. Was it a matter of brackets or the open variable $(0,1]$, which is what I tend to think. How could I amend these two functions to get the proper answer?

Comment: How does what you have address the issue of $0$?

Comment: Your definition doesn't make sense.  What is $f(.37)$?  What is $f(\frac e{\pi})$?  Also...could you include the link to the duplicate post you mention?

Comment: you asked [that very same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963930/prove-0-1-and-0-1-are-equinumerous-by-use-of-bijection) earlier, it was explained to you why your proposed solution can't work and I showed you a working one, plus the question is a duplicate...

Comment: So couldnt I add f(x) = 1/2 when x = 0?

Comment: Waiting confidently for the third installment...